# Fade a toggled div area in and out

Tags: javascript, html

I have a code to show more or less of content in a div, however, as there is a lot of content in the hidden div I would like it to fade in and fade out. Here is the code I have so far, but I don't know how to implement the fade in/out part.

Any ideas please?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleSeeMore() {
if(document.getElementById("hpreveal").style.display == 'none') {
    document.getElementById("hpreveal").style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById("seeMore").innerHTML = '[-] See Less  Options';
}
else {
    document.getElementById("hpreveal").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("seeMore").innerHTML = '[+] See More Options';        
}
}
</script>



<div id="hpreveal" style="display: none;">Lots of hidden content here</div>
 <a id="seeMore" onclick="toggleSeeMore()" href="javascript:void(0);">[+] See More Options</a>
```

Comment: How do you want to bring the out-flowed div back to the textflow?

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to add the `transition` effect to your `#textarea1` element. Unfortunately you cannot transition `display`, however, you can transition `opacity`.

See working example below:

```js
function toggleSeeMore() {
  if (document.getElementById("textarea1").style.opacity == '0') {
    document.getElementById("textarea1").style.opacity = '1';
    document.getElementById("seeMore").innerHTML = '[-] See Less  Options';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("textarea1").style.opacity = '0';
    document.getElementById("seeMore").innerHTML = '[+] See More Options';
  }
}
```

```css
#textarea1 {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<a id="seeMore" onclick="toggleSeeMore()" href="javascript:void(0);">[+] See More Options</a>

<div id="textarea1">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

This can be achieved a little more easily however by using jQuery's `.toggleFade()`:

```js
$("#seeMore").click(_ => $("#textarea1").fadeToggle(500));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="seeMore" href="javascript:void(0);">[+] See More Options</a>

<div id="textarea1">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Nick thanks for your answer. The code works but there are two issues if you can help me with. the first is I need the content to be hidden on the first view. second problem is although the content fades out it leaves a big gap where the content was. any idea how to solve this please?

Comment: Jase, the jQuery version accepts a function when the fade complete. Why not set display to none there?

Answer (score 0):

Here we hide once the fade has completed by using toggle.

```js
$("#seeMore").click(_ => $("#textarea1").fadeToggle(500, function() {
  document.querySelector('#textarea1').classList.toggle('hide');
}));
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a id="seeMore" href="javascript:void(0);">[+] See More Options</a>

<div id="textarea1">
  <p>This is some text</p>
</div>
<p>More Text</p>
```